# Research Kit: Developing app using Research kit

Tags: ios, xcode, researchkit

1. I know that apple is yet to release Research kit for development. https://developer.apple.com/researchkit/ says will be released next month.
2. But http://fortune.com/2015/03/13/apple-researchkit-apps-available/ shows the apps available using research kit.
3. I also saw release note for Xcode 6.1, 6.2 , 6.3 , 6.4 beta but no luck.

So, am i missing something to start developing using research kit or will be happy to get reason for contradict statements in point 1 & point 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Research Kit is now open and can be downloaded on [GitHub](https://github.com/researchkit/researchkit). [Here's the guide](http://researchkit.github.io/docs/docs/Overview/GuideOverview.html) and [here are the reference docs](http://researchkit.github.io/docs/index.html).

Comment: thats the master stroke @Fennelouski.

Answer (score 5):

Apple ResearchKit apps are being developed by Apple and internal health partners. Those apps aren't made by people with public SDK, rather internal Apple engineers working with those health companies.

EDIT:

Its [out](https://github.com/researchkit/researchkit), Fennelouski beat me to it <3

Comment: Yes, This sound logical & realised that those app are developed by apple medical partners. Thanks @Schemetrical

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question is : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34081792/3193017

You can create boolean answer and multiple choice answer format using this.